# Facebook token for searching groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token, facebook-group

I have created an application on developers.facebook.com from my profile. Get APP ID, APP SECRET and generate TOKEN. Now, when I send the request like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=media&type=page&access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

is ok, but when I try to send the request for GROUP, like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=media&type=group&access_token=MY_TOKEN
```

I get the error

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Seems I have permissions problem. I set the permissions `friends_groups`, `user_friends`, `user_groups` to the account, but.. still the same error...

Can you please tall me what am I doing wrong? Maybe I need a different token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you're using an App AccessToken for an endpoint (object type) which needs a user AccessToken. See the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search

It's stating

*"All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request. The type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.
Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
All other endpoints require a user access token."*